# What is $\Sigma\cap\Sigma^*$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, formal-languages

Let $\Sigma^*$ be set of all strings over symbols $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$. Adopting the most common definitions what is $\Sigma\cap\Sigma^*$? I'm aware that this question is ambiguous. I just wonder what the most generally accepted convention is. Is it $\varnothing$ or $\Sigma$?

Comment: I would say that the standard assumptions about what a symbol is in this case would lead to $\Sigma\cap\Sigma^*=\emptyset$.

Comment: Clearly the intersection is Sigma. The same is true for all languages.

Comment: If you were following a type-theoretic style of mathematical foundations, the answer would be "the question is a type error": roughly, in Coq style notation for example, you would usually have $\Sigma$ is of type `Type`, $\Sigma^*$ is defined to be `list Sigma : Type`, and intersection requires two objects of type `Ensemble X` for some `X : Type`, so you have a mismatch.  In general, whenever a type mismatch of this sort happens, that means that mathematicians will (informally) tend to think the question is meaningless to think about.

Comment: Similarly, if you have a situation where the answer in ZFC foundations depends on the details of encoding, then mathematicians will tend to think the question is meaningless to think about.  So for example, if you have an encoding where it happens that $b = aa$ as a list, then you would have $b = aa \in \Sigma \cap \Sigma^*$ whereas in general you could also have $\Sigma \cap \Sigma^* = \emptyset$ as others have observed.

Answer (score 1):

In any book of [automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) or combinatorics on words, $\Sigma$ is the alphabet and $\Sigma^*$ is the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on the alphabet $\Sigma$. Let me add that $\Sigma^n$ usually denotes the set of words of length $n$, so that $\Sigma^0 = \{1\}$, the one-element set containing the empty word $1$, $\Sigma^1 = \Sigma$ and
$$
\Sigma^* = \bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} \Sigma^n
$$
In particular, $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma \cap \Sigma^* = \Sigma$.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on how you choose to encode lists, to require that the one-element lists correspond exactly to their contents?  If, on the other hand, for example you represent $n$-element lists as functions $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \} \to \Sigma$, then the one-element list with $a$ would be equal to $\{ (0, a) \}$ and not $a$.  And then, if you chose to use a disjoint union instead of a union (so you don't have to worry about whether $\Sigma^m$ and $\Sigma^n$ overlap for $m \ne n$), then the corresponding element of the disjoint union would be something like $(1,\{(0,a)\})$.

Comment: This is just a universally accepted notation in computer science, in combinatorics on words and on formal power series. $\Sigma^n$ corresponds to the concatenation product of $n$ copies of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Absolutely not. If $n \not= m$, $\Sigma^n$ is disjoint from $\Sigma^m$. This would of course be different if $\Sigma$ was a language, but here $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ is the alphabet.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Why would you take the disjoint union? Aren’t the sets already disjoint since they consist of functions with different domains?

Comment: ^Is this what you are saying @J.-E.Pin

Comment: Am I missing something @DanielSchepler?

Comment: Sure, it just so happens that in the standard encoding, $\Sigma^m$ and $\Sigma^n$ don't overlap.  But that's an argument that again dives into the details of ZFC encodings, which I personally would consider extraneous noise that's not really relevant to anything in theories using formal languages.  So I personally would just skip straight over that noise by going to the disjoint union.